# how can use 1 cross join and 2 left join in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

How can I use 1 cross join and 2 left joins (sum group by) in one MySQL db query?

The following works but the count results is wrong (it returns both `COUNT` - same result and wrong result).

```
SELECT 
    n_users.username, n_users.email,
    COUNT(n_messages.ads_id ) AS msg_cnt, 
    COUNT(`n_coversation`.user_id ) AS cnv_cnt,
    SUM(n_transaction.debit), SUM(n_transaction.credit) 

FROM 
    n_users JOIN (n_ads , n_messages) ON 
        (n_ads.user_id=n_users.id AND  n_messages.ads_id=n_ads.id )    
    LEFT JOIN n_coversation ON  (n_coversation.user_id=n_users.id) 
    LEFT JOIN n_transaction ON (n_transaction.user_id=n_users.id)

WHERE  
    n_users.id =5

GROUP BY 
    n_transaction.user_id
```

Comment: Have you tried using `HAVING n_users.id = 5` instead of `WHERE`? (written after the `GROUP BY` clause)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'n_users.id' in 'having clause'

Comment: Ah, sorry... of course! I meant `HAVING n_transaction.user_id = 5`. And maybe try to group by `n_users.id`, since this is the original column and not the foreign key...